# How can I move a transform in the "forward direction"?

Tags: c++, math, geometry, physics

I would like to move my Transform forward, which I am using directly for my object. Rather than just move it forward in a particular axis (such as z), is there a way I can move it in the direction that the Transform would be facing? For example, by default I would go down the Z axis perfectly, however, if I rotate my transform on the Y axis and want to go "forward" it would not be directly down the Z, but also a little in the direction I rotated it.

I believe I need to calculate the forward vector, however, that is all I can seem to find. I can't find anything on if that is correct, or how to do it. How can I move a transform in the "forward direction" while having a 4x4 matrix (row major).

This isn't for my game camera, but rather just for my game object. There for, I only have my Transform matrix, which was built from my rotation matrix, scale matrix and position.

Comment: I'm a bit lost... You basically want to do a translation about some vector that has been subject to some rotation?

Comment: I bet it's an issue related to the way you're multiplying your rotation, position, and scaling matrices to form the final transformation matrix. (Matrix multiplication is *not* commutative!) Try swapping the order of multiplication of the rotation and position matrices and see what happens.

Comment: @JakobS.: I would like to move the transform in a forward direction.

Comment: First: You want to move your object, not the transform. Second: Answer my question ;)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then yes, that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can either extract the third column (or row, depending on order of multiplication) from the matrix, and that will be the forward (or backwards, depending on which direction "down" is). This will give you the destination vector for the the z-axis.

Equivalently, you can multiply the vector `new Vector4(0,0,1,0)` (or `new Vector4(0,0,-1,0)`) with the matrix (or the vector with the matrix). Note that the fourth coordinate is zero instead of one, since you don't want any translation. This will give you the direction the z-axis is transformed into.

This would also work with just the 3x3 rotation matrix. In this case, just drop the last coordinate from the vector above.

The result will be the vector that points "forward". You can add this to the position or translation matrix/vector.